# って having another usage beside as a quotation particle?

Tags: particle-って

I encountered this sentence while reading manga:

> もし朝飯に嫌いなピーマンが多かったからテンション低い**って**ばれたら...

But I have no idea why the って particle is being used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is just a quotative って. Admittedly 'quotative' may make it sound narrower, but

'If it gets out *that* "I'm low on energy because there were lots of peppers, which I hate, in my breakfast"...'

(I don't mind peppers myself but peppers for breakfast sounds weird)